# Updating udev rules fails during docker build

Tags: docker, udev

I'm trying to build my docker image that installs JLink, but when trying to update udev rules it fails. Udev is installed before the part that fails.

Docker part that fails:

```
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN wget --post-data 'accept_license_agreement=accepted&non_emb_ctr=confirmed' https://www.segger.com/downloads/jlink/JLink_Linux_x86_64.deb
RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y ./JLink_Linux_x86_64.deb \
 && rm JLink_Linux_x86_64.deb
```

Terminal print:

```
#0 14.68 Setting up jlink (7.861) ...
#0 14.68 Updating udev rules via udevadm...
#0 14.68 Failed to reload udevadm rules, retrying...
#0 14.69 Failed to send reload request: No such file or directory
#0 14.69 Error: Failed to update udevadm rules.
#0 14.69 dpkg: error processing package jlink (--configure):
#0 14.69  installed jlink package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
#0 14.69 Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-13+deb11u5) ...
#0 14.71 Errors were encountered while processing:
#0 14.71  jlink
#0 14.72 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
------
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get update  && apt-get install -y ./JLink_Linux_x86_64.deb  && rm JLink_Linux_x86_64.deb]: exit code: 100

 *  The terminal process "/bin/bash '-c', 'docker-compose -f docker/docker-compose.yml build'" terminated with exit code: 17. 
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

I tried running the exact same steps outside of docker, and it worked like a charm. What could be the culprit?

Comment: Could you try sudo apt-get update -y

Comment: Tried, but same problem occurs.

Comment: A Docker container doesn't have access to host devices and isn't running system daemons, so it doesn't seem surprising that `udevadm` would fail.  Can you somehow cause the package to avoid running this command?  Is this in fact the Java [tag:jlink] tool, or something else?

Comment: @DavidMaze I will look into avoiding the package. And no it isn't Java jlink. It's Nordic J-link. Removing jlink tag.

Comment: @Sri the problem persists when rm JLink_Linux_x86_64.deb is removed